# Symfony 2 User security from one bundle to other bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony 2 and never used any framework before.

I created 2 bundles, one for core site which url is as root `/` it is `DefaultBundle` then I created a new `UserBundle` and set all the routing to `/user/` the login page is `/user/login` and it is working fine.

So far I am able to login the user and every thing seems working.

Question really is, how can I check in `DefaultBundle` that a user is logged in, so I show them `Welcome User` instead of `login/register` links on top right side of the front end website.

p.s. I dont need FOSuserBundle as answer,

below is from my security.yml file

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
       Aala\Vital\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
          algorithm: plaintext
#              encode_as_base64: false
#              iterations: 1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_MOD:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MOD, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    user_area:
      entity: {class: AalaVitalUserBundle:User, property: email}

firewalls:

    login:
        pattern:  ^/user/login$
        security: false
        anonymous: true

    user_area:
        pattern:    ^/user
        form_login:
            login_path: /user/login
            check_path: /user/login_check
            post_only: true
            default_target_path: /user/
        logout:
            path:   /user/logout
            target: /user/

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        security: true
        anonymous: ~


access_control:
    - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

My Folder Structure is as follows

```
-src
    -Aala
        -Vital
            -FronendBundle
            -UserBundle
```

## Edit:

Is this can be done with dependency injection? if yes how to do that...

Comment: question: do you manage to create a new security.yml file inside the new bundle? if so, how?

Comment: No, I didnt created security.yml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved

To share the authentication between two firewalls use `context`. Below is the updated firewalls section from my security.yml file

```
firewalls:

    login:
        pattern:  ^/user/login$
        security: false
        anonymous: true

    user_area:
        pattern:    ^/user
        context: primary_auth
        form_login:
            login_path: /user/login
            check_path: /user/login_check
            post_only: true
            default_target_path: /user/
        logout:
            path:   /user/logout
            target: /user/

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        context: primary_auth
        security: true
        anonymous: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs in a controller:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    if($user->isAuthenticated()) {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this and got `Fatal error: Call to a member function isAuthenticated() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\myVital\src\Aala\Vital\FrontendBundle\Controller\PageController.php on line 12`

Comment: Please post the complete security.yml file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the routes for both bundles to be behind the same firewall for `$user = $this->getUser();` to work. Then you can allow anonymous access using ACL if you'd like a certain part of the site to be unauthenticated.

```
firewalls:
    site:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /user/login
            check_path: /user/login_check
            post_only: true
            default_target_path: /
        logout:
            path:   /user/logout
            target: /user/

access_control:
    - { path: ^/user/, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

Comment: I have tried that and it takes me to `/user/login` on every page like `/contact-us`

Comment: Combination of ACL and a single firewall is definitely the way to go, I just have some issue with this security config. I'll look at it more when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the dosc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#access-control-in-templates).

```
{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
    {{ 'Welcome ' ~ app.user.username }}
    <a href="{{ path('logout_route') }}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ path('login_route') }}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

Change `login_route` and `logout_route` to meet routes of your application.

Why don't you want to use FOSUserBundle? It's a very good bundle, written by core members and e.g. you can find this code [right here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/layout.html.twig).

Comment: i tried your solution and got `The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.`